# "No account object provided to acquireTokenSilent" error with updated versions of Chrome

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-teams

I've been developing an automation tool using `SeleniumBasic` that worked for over two years.

The tool is navigates the `MS Teams Web App` and provides interactions with multiple chat rooms throughout the evening (using the `Classic App` and not migrated to the new yet).

I receive the following error when I try to switch to an `iFrame` after moving from the main window.  It seems to have happened after Chrome was updated to version 120.

[image]

Minimal code example:

```vb
If myChrome.IsElementPresent(FindBy.XPath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'experience-container')]")) Then
    myChrome.SwitchToFrame myChrome.FindElementByXPath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'experience-container')]")
End If
```

The code has not changed, so what has, and what do I need to do to allow it to keep the User Account?  I've never supplied anything as I've just navigated the existing elements within the frame and allowed the `Teams Web App` to process it all.

Comment: You might try using Geckodriver/Firefox instead.

Comment: I wish I could - the company only allows Chrome / Edge, and because SeleniumBasic opens in known test mode, we are using Edge as our main so sites don't ban the IP's due to the test/bot headers.  I did find a workaround, which has so far lasted, and I'll post this as my answer after working through things tonight - if the issue stays away successfully, then we'll count it a success, even if it is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When researching this error, I found many references to `MASL` failing etc., but couldn't see where or how this was occurring.  It appears with the updated versions of Chrome, there is a large difference in how Chrome itself is handling all the manipulation of the `Teams Web App` and is now capable of detecting when the bot clicks on something vs the user.

The only way I could workaround this was by forcing the bot to open the URL to whichever portion of Teams I was trying to utilize (such as the Calendar) an then proceed from there.

It's a tad kludgy unfortunately, but it beats having to try and develop some way of getting MASL to work with `VBA/SeleniumBasic` (I'll gladly accept an answer that has a way of solving this deeper need - must be `Excel VBA`, using `SeleniumBasic` - but for now, this works.)